# Post to ActiveX - differing results between browsers

Tags: javascript, activex

I'm controlling an ActiveX control via Javascript/JQuery. The control is a video player that plays a certain type of format we require, that standard players don't support.

Anyhow, one of the API commands of the player is to seek to a certain point in the video, the command goes along the lines of...

```
o = new PlayerObject("player");
o.createPlayer(width, height);
o.UseMediaServer(ipAddress);
o.UseFile(file);
o.Play();
o.Seek(30); //This doesn't work in Chrome
```

This works exactly the same across all browsers, in terms of loading, playing, etc, but the only difference is that in Chrome, the Seek(secs) command doesn't seen to send the data correctly to the ActiveX control, and the result is that the ActiveX control always cues to to the start of the clip, like it's interpreting the data as zero(0) instead of the actual value. I think this probably boils down to types, as the ActiveX control is expecting a LONG. Mozilla and IE seem to send it correctly, but not Chrome.

I'm unsure where to go from here, any ideas?

Edit: Obviously it's a plugin that wraps the ActiveX [link-to-plugin](http://umediaserver.net/umediaserver/BrowsersPlugin.html)

Comment: Internet Explorer is the only browser that supports ActiveX at all, so your question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: There hasn't been a supported browser called "Mozilla" since 2006. Do you mean Firefox?

Comment: Well, you say that, but I can 100% confirm that I am loading an ActiveX control [Link-to-control](http://www.umediaserver.net/umediaserver/BrowsersPlugin.html)  and [link-to-API](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zcg2r36o41tbmj7/ActiveX%20API.htm) and testing in all browsers. I've been working on it work that past 3 weeks, I think I'd know where it's working or not, and in which browser. Also, is questioning my use of 'Mozilla' really constructive? In CSS, we still type 'moz' to target certain Firefox, the company is named Mozilla, I don't think I'm too far from the mark! Thanks for the input though.

Comment: That's a plugin, not ActiveX (although the Internet Explorer version probably uses ActiveX).

Comment: Fair enough, the company calls it an ActiveX control, and quote "Other browsers such as FireFox, Chrome and Safari must use plugin that wraps the ActiveX control" - so I think my question is still valid.

Comment: It's worth also mentioning that as an activeX control (with or without a plugin wrapper), it will only work on Windows, so Mac users or mobile users will probably not be able to see this content.

Comment: That's fine, it's a known limitation, as this is a solution being developed for a company I work for to use 'in house' - won't be available to the masses!